# SonarQube Fails With java.lang.StackOverflowError - How to determine specific file causing error

Tags: java, linux, sonarqube

I am trying to scan some source-code, particularly some Java source files, that fail with `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. I used my very favourite search engine, Google, to research this some and found some possible solutions.

The best solution I found is here: http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/StackOverflowException-on-JAVA-AST-analysis-SonarQube-4-5-1-with-java-plugin-2-6-td5030537.html

This solution however does not address explicitly how to a) set the **SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS** environment variable or b) how to locate the specific file that is causing the error in the first place so one can either 1) exclude it, 2) delete it, or 3) figure out some way to mitigate the the problem so the scan can complete successfully.

My questions are:

1. How to find out which specific file is causing the error, *StackOverflowError* in this case
2. How to set the 'SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS' variable on a Linux operating-system

I have tried to debug the problem in sonar-runner with the -X and -e switches respectively. To run an analysis I use the following command: 
`sonar-runner -X -Dsonar.properties=sonar-project.properties &> debug_dump.txt` or `sonar-runner -e -Dsonar.properties=sonar-project.properties &> dump.txt`. This did not help though.

By the way I am using **sonar-runner-2.4**.

To set the environment variable SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS I went to the .bash_profile in my $HOME folder and put this entry in it:`SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS=" -Xss1600k"` Will this actually increase the stack-size for **sonar-runner**?  **Also, will I need to restart the operating-system or will the change take effect on the next scan?**

Thank-you for reading this post.

Comment: Can you precise which version of sonarqube you are using ? also which version of sonar-java plugin is installed on your server ? and finally can you share the whole stack trace which is causing the stackoverflow error ? That would really help to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: *"will I need to restart the operating-system or will the change take effect on the next scan"* - just do a `. .bash_profile` to get it executed.

Comment: @GergelyBacso What do you mean? Will not 'sonar-runner' pick up the environment-variable from the profile? Also, the command you are suggesting `..bash_profile`?  I do not think the hidden file .bash_profile is an executable file anyway... Maybe I am completely ignorant of something so please help me understand. :D

Comment: @benzonico The SonarQube server version is: 4.5.5 The Java plug-in version is: 3.7 I cannot share the entire stack trace because it would violate the company policy. What should I be looking for in said stack trace?

Comment: @benzonico In the stack-trace it ends with hundreds possibly thousands of probably recursive calls shown here: `at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:128)
        at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)`

Comment: This has been fixed in latest version of java plugin, please upgrade to 3.9

Comment: I only see an option to update to 3.8. Was it fixed in 3.8 by chance?

Comment: @benzonico I updated the Java plug-in to 3.8 but I still receive the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you precised in comments, it sounds like you are encountering this bug : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1346

As shown in jira ticket it has been fixed in 3.9. So you should upgrade to that version (and thus maybe upgrade SonarQube to latest LTS version (4.5.6 if I'm not mistaking)). Workaround would be to deactivate the rule S2695 while waiting for upgrade.